# SVN: How to download a specific release of a project?

Tags: svn

I have a repository address:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/
My aim is to download each release of the ant project separately from this online repo.

I know that ant has a release 1.3.

(1) What is the command line instruction to download the release 1.3?

(2) How can I find all other release tags of ant? (such as 1.4, 1.5 etc.)

I am using Apache Subversion command line tools.

Comment: Did you try to read the SVN documentation at least?

Comment: @royalTS I tried. My google returns many solutions that talk about downloading a revision like r123456, but I am trying to find if there is any easy way to get a particular release directly using the publicly announced release tag instead of internal revision number(such as v1.4 instead of r123456).

Comment: @royalTS Ain’t nobody got time fo’ that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/

Maybe you want `svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/ANT_13/` or if you don't want history `svn export http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/ANT_13/`

You can list the "versions" (tags) with command `svn ls http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/`

Maybe you want to check the http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/branches/ directory too.

Answer (score 0):

For release version based download you need make sure that, it is been tagged accordingly. Otherwise you need to get the sources by the svn revision number.

to get version 1234

$ svn up -r1234

$ svn checkout -r 1234 url://repo-path
or
svn checkout url://repo-path@1234

If you don't know the version, may be you go though the svn log and find the svn version

svn log | grep -i "release 1.3"